# Update Gradle to Version 7.0.2

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

Updating Gradle from version 4.2.0 to 7.0.2. ended up in an error during minifying with R8. (Using Java 1.8)

Unfortunately, the error message is not very telling (see below).

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.0.69.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.w.a(SourceFile:68)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.w.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.w.a(SourceFile:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8.java:29)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:3)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:301)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:592)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task.doTaskAction(R8Task.kt:443)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:94)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor512.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    ... 118 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.r8.graph.B.F()" because "<parameter1>" is null
```

Did anybody face / solve the same problem?

Comment: Which Java version?

Comment: In Android Studio terminal try this command ./gradlew clean

Comment: @MartinZeitler Java Version 1.8

Comment: @Gitesh cleaning didn't help